# Ho to add mixed multiple fields in a node

Tags: entities, media

I'm searching for a way to add unlimited amount of multiple *mixed* fields in a node.

In few words there is such a situation: let's say, I have a content type with fields "picture" and "text", and for both of them "number of values" is set to "unlimited", which lets user to add unlimited amount of photos and unlimited amount of text blocks.

What I want to achieve is that content editor could mix those two fields together, like it is possible to change places of entries of one field. The example of entry could be like this:

editor is adding a block of text, then a picture, then another picture, then again a block of text, etc.

The problem is that it is not clear what could be the amount of these elements and their sequence may change depending on circumstances.

I know that it is possible to do this with Views, but that makes the work of editor much more complicated and he/she cannot see the "full view" at the same time, so maybe it is possible somehow to merge two types of fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module ?

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can be attached.
>
> A field collection is internally represented as an entity, which is embedded in the host entity. Thus, if desired field collections may be viewed and edited separately too.

It allows to combine multiple fields and treated as a single field.

Here is the [doc](http://drupal.org/node/1353926).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great, I didn't find this one while searching! Will deffinitely try this one straight away, thanks!